# How do I connect to a Minecraft Server through my friend's IP in version 1.8.9?

Tags: vpn, ip, minecraft

I want to be able to connect to servers in Minecraft 1.8.9 using my friends IP. Is there any way I can do this? Is it possible to use some kind of VPN or something? This is because I want to connect to Hypixel without using my IP but if I use a VPN I can get banned for hacking if someone else used the same ip while hacking.

Answer (score 0):

By "using my friend's IP", you mean going out onto the public internet as if you were them, instead of yourself?  You will have to convince your friend to host a VPN for you.

Comment: How would he host a VPN? Can you provide a step by step of some sort?

Comment: And how would I connect to it?

Comment: Well, your friend would probably have to buy a VPN appliance, or a wifi router with a built in VPN, then you would connect to it the same way as any other VPN.  You would probably need to combine that with a dynamic DNS service as your friends IP address changes.